# Reading a file into a dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a file:

```
Fruits:
I love apples
I also love bananas
who even likes pears?
<<<END
Bananas are yellow 
apples are not yellow..
<<<END
Vegetables:
Anything green is gross
I don’t like vegetables
<<<END
Peas are disgusting
Who even likes peas
Is potato a vegetable?
<<<END
```

I want to take the lines that end in ":" such as "Fruits" and "Vegetables" and make them the key of the dictionary. And make every line that is under the key, a list of tuples.

So far I have:

```
def read_file(file):
    dic = {}
    lst = []
    with open(file,'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.strip("\n") == "<<<END":
                continue
            elif line.endswith(":\n"):
                a = line.strip(":\n")
                dic[a] = []
            else:
                key = line.strip(":\n")
                dic[a].append(key)
        return dic
```

I want the program to return:

```
{'Fruits': [("I love apples", "I also love bananas", "who even like  pears"),("Bananas are yellow", "apples are not yellow..")], 'Vegetables':[("Anything green is gross", "I don't like vegetables"),("Peas are disgusting", "Who even likes peas", "Is potato a vegetable?")]}
```

It returns:

```
{'Fruits': ["I love apples", "I also love bananas", "who even like  pears","Bananas are yellow", "apples are not yellow.."], Vegetables: ["Anything green is gross", "I don't like vegetables","Peas are disgusting", "Who even likes peas", "Is potato a vegetable?"]}
```

Comment: Maybe because you're using `"<<<EOT"` instead of `"<<<END"` as specified in your file.

Comment: It returns {'fruits': ["I love apples", "I also love bananas", "who even like  pears","Bananas are yellow", "apples are not yellow.."], Vegetables: ["Anything green is gross", "I don't like vegetables","Peas are disgusting", "Who even likes peas", "Is potato a vegetable?"]}

Comment: Sorry it was cutting out the output when i tried posting it, so i added it as a comment above^

Answer (score 1):

Below is a solution, keeping your code almost intact. The idea is making a list until you get an `<<<END` and append the tuple(made from the list) to the result list.

```
def read_file(file):
    dic = {}
    lst = []
    with open(file,'r') as file:
        temp= []
        key = None
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == "<<<END":
                dic[key].append(tuple([key] + temp))
                temp = []
                continue
            elif line.endswith(":"):
                key = line.strip(":")
                dic[key] = []
            else:
                temp.append(line)
        return dic


print(read_file('test2.txt'))
```

Output:

```
{'Vegetables': [('Vegetables', 'Anything green is gross', 'I don\xe2\x80\x99t like vegetables'), ('Vegetables', 'Peas are disgusting', 'Who even likes peas', 'Is potato a vegetable?')], 'Fruits': [('Fruits', 'I love apples', 'I also love bananas', 'who even likes pears?'), ('Fruits', 'Bananas are yellow', 'apples are not yellow..')]}
```

Comment: @Johnny, glad to know it helps. if you feel this particular answer satisfies your question, you can consider accepting the answer. See how to accept from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: how would i make it return: {'Vegetables': [('vegetables','Anything green is gross', 'I don\xe2\x80\x99t like vegetables'), ('vegetables','Peas are disgusting', 'Who even likes peas', 'Is potato a vegetable?')], 'Fruits': [('Fruits','I love apples', 'I also love bananas', 'who even likes pears?'), ('Fruits','Bananas are yellow', 'apples are not yellow..')]}

Comment: What do you mean by *make it return* ?

Comment: how do i make it so the first element in the tuple is the name of the key, as i posted above^

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def read_file(file):
    dic = {}
    lst = []
    same_dict = False 
    with open(file,'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.endswith(":\n"):
                a = line.strip(":\n")
                dic[a] = []
            else:
                if line.strip("\n") == "<<<END":
                    dic[a].append(tuple(lst))
                    lst = []
                else:
                    key = line.strip("\n")
                    lst.append(key)
   return dic
```

With reference to your new requirement,

```
def read_file(file):
    dic = {}
    lst = []
    same_dict = False 
    with open(file,'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.endswith(":\n"):
                a = line.strip(":\n")
                dic[a] = []
            else:
                if line.strip("\n") == "<<<END":
                    dic[a].append(tuple([a]+lst))
                    lst = []
                else:
                    key = line.strip("\n")
                    lst.append(key)
    return dic

print(read_file('temp.txt'))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: how would i make it return: {'Vegetables': [('vegetables','Anything green is gross', 'I don\xe2\x80\x99t like vegetables'), ('vegetables','Peas are disgusting', 'Who even likes peas', 'Is potato a vegetable?')], 'Fruits': [('Fruits','I love apples', 'I also love bananas', 'who even likes pears?'), ('Fruits','Bananas are yellow', 'apples are not yellow..')]} how would i make it return so that the first element in every tuple is the key

Comment: I dont understand the use of it, but I have edited the answer, kindly mark it as correct if it serves your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

i think you've got it mostly right, just missing some steps to keep your different groups of data separate. try:

```
def read_file(path):
   d = {}
   with open(path, 'r') as f:
       lines = f.read().splitlines()
       group = None
       parts = []
       for line in lines:
           if line.endswith(":"):
               group = line[:-1]
               d[group] = []
           else:
               if line == "<<<END":
                   #  tuple-ize existing data
                   d[group].append(tuple(parts))
                   parts = []

               else:
                   # add to existing data
                   k = line[:-1]
                   parts.append(line)
       return d
```

which for me returns:

```
>>> read_file('/tmp/1')
{'Vegetables': [('Anything green is gross', 'I don\xe2\x80\x99t like vegetables'), ('Peas are disgusting', 'Who even likes peas', 'Is potato a vegetable?')], 'Fruits': [('I love apples', 'I also love bananas', 'who even likes pears?'), ('Bananas are yellow ', 'apples are not yellow..')]}
>>>
```

i just added an explicit conversion of data via tuple() and added a temp variable 'parts' to keep track of data outside of the final dict.